# How to resolve socket error when connecting to imap.gmail.com via port 993 using imaplib?

Tags: imaplib

```
import imaplib
s = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1138, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/imaplib.py", line 1149, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 561, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a (possible temporary) network error rather than a software problem.

Try it again now, or from another machine.